# GNU Make: Remove all parts of filename after first dot

Tags: filenames, gnu-make

In a GNU Makefile (on an Ubuntu Linux system), how may I remove the filename suffix of each filename in a list in such a way that the filenames are truncated at the first dot?

Suppose I have

```
NAMES = file1.a.b.c file2.x.y.z file3.b file4.foo
```

where the names may come from a filename globbing expansion using `$(wildcard file*)`.

I would like to end up with

```
NEWNAMES = file1 file2 file3 file4
```

or possibly even

```
NEWNAMES = file1.quux file2.quux file3.quux file4.quux
```

(not necessarily in this order)

The `$(basename ...)` function only strips the *last* suffix from the names.

In a shell supporting arrays, I would have used something like `"${names[@]%%.*}"` or `"${names[@]/%.*/.quux}"`.

---

The reason for wanting to do this is that we're working with a bioinformatics environment where files have a known filename prefix, but their suffix may be any combination of `.fa`, `.fas`, `.fasta` (etc.), with the possibility of these suffixes doubling up (as in `.fa.fa`) and also having a file compressor suffix, such as `.gz`, at the end.

We would like to transform the filenames into normalised `prefix.suffix` filenames in the Makefile, regardless of how complex the initial filename suffix was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do it with make functions without using a shell, you can use something like this:

```
NAMES := $(foreach F,$(wildcard file*),$(firstword $(subst ., ,$F)))
```

Comment: Yes, and then we could use `$(addsuffix .quux, $(foreach ... ))`.  This is slightly neater.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what platforms are targeted here (do we have a SUSv3 compliant /bin/sh) as well as any requirements on the names.

If it's acceptable that names can't contain whitespace, I think a simple

```
NEWNAMES = $(shell for p in $(NAMES); do echo $${p%%.*};done)
```

comes close enough and is easy to understand.

Comment: Sorry, this is on Ubuntu. I have updated the question with that missing info. I will test your answer.

Comment: Yes, this appears to be an easy answer that we could use, assuming filenames with no spaces or globbing characters, obviously. Accepting this for the time being. Much thanks!

Comment: You should really use `:=` here not `=`.  If `NEWNAMES` is only used in one place it's no big deal but if it's used all over it can make a difference in runtime.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a more flexible approach, you can use [gmtt](https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt), a GNUmake library:

```
include gmtt-master/gmtt-master/gmtt.mk

NAMES = file1.a.b.c file2.x.y.z file3.b file4.foo

$(info $(foreach fn,$(NAMES),$(call glob-match,$(fn),*.*)$(newline)))

NEWNAMES = file1.middle.quux file2.middle.quux file3.middle.quux file4.more.middle.quux

$(info $(foreach fn,$(NEWNAMES),$(call glob-match,$(fn),*.*.quux)$(newline)))
```

Output:

```
  $ make
 file1 . a.b.c
  file2 . x.y.z
  file3 . b
  file4 . foo

 file1 . middle .quux
  file2 . middle .quux
  file3 . middle .quux
  file4 . more.middle .quux

make: *** Keine Ziele.  Schluss.
```

The glob-matcher returns a list of separated strings which you can process further.